# How to keep PHP and MySQL of ampps as default in MacOSX?

Tags: macos, php, mysql

I'm using MacOS X 10.6.2. I want to use AMPPS http://www.ampps.com/ as my local development server so my question is how do I keep my AMPPS PHP & MySQL default?

Answer (score 6):

if you meant how to set AMPPS `php` and `mysql` as default, then you must define this line in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/Applications/AMPPS/php/bin:/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

This makes the OS search for binaries in this paths before the default ones.

Answer (score 1):

You should find two options in AMPPS "Start AMPPS on Starup" and "Start Apache & MySQL on Application startup".

These options can be found exactly at:
Right click on AMPPS Dock Icon -> Configuration -> AMPPS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a newer version of AMPPS make sure you choose the proper folder path.

```
export PATH="/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/bin:/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

instead of plain "php" add the version.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used AMPPS but I reckon you must stop web sharing from system preferences -> sharing, to leave free port 80. What do you mean as default? Always on? There should be a start server at boot... nothing really difficult.

I would use just mac's web sharing which is Apache, you can turn on PHP by uncommenting this line:

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

in /etc/apache/httpd.conf. You can use one of the latest PHP versions from: http://php-osx.liip.ch/.

MySql server has an easy dmg installer. If you want to be a good programmer, you should be able to set up and know your environment.